# Heroku Push Error H10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, railtie

I have been trying for the past couple of days to fix an error that keeps occuring once I have pushed my app to Heroku.

The app works fine in development when booted up on Webrick but for some reason I keep receiving an `Application Error` page when trying to load my app on Heroku.

I have the following log report - does anyone know how I can fix this?

```
 2012-10-21T14:17:52+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.0 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:23771
 2012-10-21T14:17:52+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/uploaders/cv_uploader.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant CarrierWave (NameError)
 2012-10-21T14:17:52+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
 2012-10-21T14:17:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:225:in `constantize'
 2012-10-21T14:17:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:256:in `safe_constantize'
 2012-10-21T14:17:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:66:in `safe_constantize'
 2012-10-21T14:17:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:152:in `_default_wrap_model'
 2012-10-21T14:17:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:169:in `_set_wrapper_defaults'
 2012-10-21T14:17:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/abstract_controller/railties/routes_helpers.rb:7:in `block(2 levels) in with'
 2012-10-21T14:17:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:133:in `inherited'
 2012-10-21T14:17:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `each'
 2012-10-21T14:17:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_controller/railties/paths.rb:7:in `block (2 levels)in with'
 2012-10-21T14:17:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
 2012-10-21T14:17:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/app/controllers/apps_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
 2012-10-21T14:17:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `block in eager_load!'
 2012-10-21T14:17:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
 2012-10-21T14:17:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
 2012-10-21T14:17:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
 2012-10-21T14:17:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `each'
 2012-10-21T14:17:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `eager_load!'
 2012-10-21T14:17:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:54:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
 2012-10-21T14:17:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
 2012-10-21T14:17:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
 2012-10-21T14:17:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
 2012-10-21T14:17:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
 2012-10-21T14:17:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
 2012-10-21T14:17:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
 2012-10-21T14:17:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
 2012-10-21T14:17:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
 2012-10-21T14:17:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:1:in `new'
 2012-10-21T14:17:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
 2012-10-21T14:17:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
 2012-10-21T14:17:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
 2012-10-21T14:17:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
 2012-10-21T14:17:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
 2012-10-21T14:17:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
 2012-10-21T14:17:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
 2012-10-21T14:17:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
 2012-10-21T14:17:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `require'
 2012-10-21T14:17:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
 2012-10-21T14:17:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
 2012-10-21T14:17:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
 2012-10-21T14:17:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
 2012-10-21T14:17:53+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
 2012-10-21T14:17:53+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
 2012-10-21T14:17:54+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET secure-ocean-9819.herokuapp.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Any help on this really would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Do you have CarrierWave in your Gemfile?

Comment: Hi Max, No I don't currently have it in my gemfile. I did but then removed it as the code that is accessible to the user doesn't use Carrierwave (the actual code that might access Carrierwave though is definitely still in there though) - is this causing the error?

Comment: Hi I have added in Carrierwave and seem to have got past this error now and on to just a basic 500 error now. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Has your problem been resolved I have some few things you can try let me know as soon as you can because i recently ran into similar problem